# C# Get Button Click from another Form

Tags: c#, forms, timer

**I want to make that you can start a Timer from Form2 and in Form1 the Timer is counting down.
Thats what I already made.
Now I want just that you can Stop that Timer in Form1**

**Form1:**

```
        public static Form1 instance;
        public Label tb1;
        // public Timer tm1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            instance = this;
            tb1 = labelCountdown;
        }

        private void buttonStopSTD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Stops the Shutdown
        {
            Process.Start("shutdown", "-a");
        }
```

**Form2:**

```
        private void button10m_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seconds = Convert.ToInt32(600);
            timer1.Start();
            Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 600");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Timer
        {
            string off = "Shutdown not set";
            if (seconds < 1) // If Timer hits 0 it turns the Timer off and prints "Shutdown not set"
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                labelCdown.Text = off;
                Form1.instance.tb1.Text = ("Shutdown not set");
            }
            else // If the Timer is above 0 it normally works
            {
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds--);
                string str = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                labelCdown.Text = str;
                Form1.instance.tb1.Text = ("Shutdown in: " + str);
            }
        }
```

I tried simply stoping the Timer over Form1: Form1.instance.Timer.Stop();

Comment: Move timer to Form1. Since you using Form1 public static instance, you may start it from Form2 (through `Form1.instance.timer` for example) and stop from Form1. I really trying hard not to mention the concept of your implementation)

Comment: Doesnt work "due to its protection level", I cant start a Timer from another Form. And secondly the timer1_Tick doesnt really work because it cant get the Value of Seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to start a countdown timer in Form2 and be able to stop it from Form1. However, your current code doesn't seem to have a Timer object exposed in Form1, and Form1.instance.Timer.Stop() won't work because you haven't defined a Timer property. To achieve your goal, you can create a Timer object in Form2 and expose methods to start and stop it from both Form1 and Form2.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonStopSTD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer in Form2
        Form2.instance.StopTimer();
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    public static Form2 instance;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    }

    public void StartTimer(int seconds)
    {
        // Start the timer with the specified number of seconds
        timer1.Start();
        // Your other timer setup logic here
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        // Your logic to handle stopping the timer here
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your timer tick logic
    }

    private void button10m_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int seconds = Convert.ToInt32(600);
        StartTimer(seconds);
    }
}
```

In Form2, I've added methods `StartTimer` and `StopTimer` that allow you to start and stop the timer. You can call these methods from Form1 to control the timer in Form2. Make sure to adapt your timer logic inside these methods accordingly.

This approach allows you to start and stop the timer in Form2 from Form1 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding of my comment.

If I understand correctly, your implementation "delegates" to `Form2` both specifying delay before shutdown and initializing (starting) timer. And from `Form1` you trying to stop timer in `Form2` for any reason. Overall target, as seen from code, is to run `shutdown.exe` after specified delay, with also displaying countdown.

I suggest you another view: use `Form2` **only to receive user's preferred delay**. Then return it into `Form1`, where declare timer and use it. In that way you don't need produce static instance, access it from somewhere - it isn't pretty well approach.

For example. Create some Form (i called it `ShutdownDelayInputForm`), where allow only input of delay value. Below is example view of it (where I also removed tool buttons like minimize, close, etc).

[image]

In code-behind of that Form you need only 2 things: a public property (to be able to receive inputted value from other Forms) and a OK button click handler. That handler should just convert user input value to integer and set it to a public property and close the Form, so code may look like this:

**ShutdownDelayInputForm.cs:**

```
public partial class ShutdownDelayInputForm : Form
{
    // Declare a public property to be able to get it's value from another Form
    public int DelayValue { get; private set; }

    public ShutdownDelayInputForm() => InitializeComponent();

    private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Try convert text input to an integer value or set 0 as default.
        // tbDelay - is name of TextBox for user input
        // Validations of value exists in other (caller) Form
        DelayValue = int.TryParse(tbDelay.Text, out int delayMilliseconds) ? delayMilliseconds : 0;
        Close();
    }
}
```

That's all! Now, in another Form (let's say, `MainForm`), we call that `ShutdownDelayInputForm`, waiting until it's closed (with `ShowDialog`) and capturing user input:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // ... some other stuff

    // Method shows a Form to user to input delay value
    private int PromptForShutdownDelay()
    {
        var shutdownDelay = 0;

        var shutdownDelayInputForm = new ShutdownDelayInputForm();
        // Pre-setup handler to capture user inputted value
        // of delay from a public property before form will be closed
        shutdownDelayInputForm.Closing += delegate
        {
            shutdownDelay = shutdownDelayInputForm.DelayValue;
        };
        // Show the form to user. With "ShowDialog" code will "stop" here
        // until form will be closed
        shutdownDelayInputForm.ShowDialog();

        return shutdownDelay;
    }
}
```

Then you can use result of `PromptForShutdownDelay` in any way: validate delay value, setup timer and shutdown, etc.

#### Usage example

I've added few controls to `MainForm` which looks like:

[image]

And used `System.Timers.Timer` for countdown. Below is full working code-behind of `MainForm`, so you can test it by yourself. Comments in code below explains what and why is used.

**MainForm.cs:**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _shutdownTimer;

    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    private void SetupShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var shutdownDelay = PromptForShutdownDelay();
        // Validate user input in some way
        if (shutdownDelay <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Delay must be an integer, greater than zero (0).\n" +
                            "Please specify correct value for shutdown delay");
            return;
        }

        // And from here we can start initializing timer
        InitializeAndRunShutdownTimer(shutdownDelay);           
    }

    private void AbortShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _shutdownTimer.Stop();
        // As example uses System.Timers.Timer, which implements IDisposable interface, we shouldn't forget to dispose it
        _shutdownTimer.Dispose();
        // Reset Form controls also safely
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        {
            // Now in reverse of timer start, enable "start" button to allow setup shutdown again
            btnSetupShutdown.Enabled = true;
            // And disable "cancel" button instead
            btnAbortShutdown.Enabled = false;
            // Reset Label value
            lblCountdown.Text = "00:00:00";
        });
    }

    private int PromptForShutdownDelay()
    {
        var shutdownDelay = 0;

        var shutdownDelayInputForm = new ShutdownDelayInputForm();
        // Pre-setup handler to capture user inputted value
        // of delay from a public property before form will be closed
        shutdownDelayInputForm.Closing += delegate
        {
            shutdownDelay = shutdownDelayInputForm.DelayValue;
        };
        // Show the form to user. With ShowDialog code will "stop" here until form will be closed
        shutdownDelayInputForm.ShowDialog();

        return shutdownDelay;
    }

    private void InitializeAndRunShutdownTimer(int shutdownDelay)
    {
        // "initialTime" is a variable, which stores user inputted delay
        // as TimeSpan, so in Form it can be pretty represented as HH:MM:SS
        var initialTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(shutdownDelay);
        lblCountdown.Text = initialTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

        // Initializing Timer with 1 second (1000 ms) interval
        _shutdownTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000)
        {
            // AutoReset needed to auto-restart timer every 1000 ms (as specified in line above)
            AutoReset = true
        };
        // Creating a handler for each timer "tick"
        _shutdownTimer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            // Check and stop the timer when countdown completed
            if (initialTime.TotalMilliseconds < 0)
            {
                // I call simply Abort button handler, 
                // which also stops and releases Timer,
                // instead of just "_shutdownTimer.Stop" here
                AbortShutdown_Click(null, null);
                // And execute shutdown.exe
                ExecuteShutdown();
                return;
            }

            // Update countdown every second. As timer's handler runs
            // as separate (non-UI) thread - update value into Label safely
            lblCountdown.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblCountdown.Text = initialTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); });
            // Subtract 1 second on each tick from initial delay.
            // That makes "countdown"
            initialTime = initialTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
        };
        // Disable button to prevent multiple countdowns
        btnSetupShutdown.Enabled = false;
        // And enable "cancel" button instead
        btnAbortShutdown.Enabled = true;
        // Run timer
        _shutdownTimer.Start();
    }

    private void ExecuteShutdown()
    {
        // You don't need to specify (pass) delay to shutdown.exe -
        // this call will execute already after delay
        // Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/s");
        MessageBox.Show("Shutdowning!!!");
    }
}
```